# How to define programming language for the `<code>` element

Tags: visual-studio, xml-documentation

How do I define programming language for the `<code>` element in XmlDocs?

I'm having XML examples, but they are highlighted as C# (since it's a C# project).

Example:

```
/// <code>
/// <![CDATA[
/// <SaveConfig>
///         <File>Web.config</File>
///         <File>App.config</File>
/// </SaveConfig>
/// ]]>
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **lang** attribute of <[code](http://www.helixoft.com/images/stories/vsdocman/help/acodexml.htm)> tag. For example:

```
<code lang="C#"></code>
<code lang="VB"></code>
```

Comment: Is it a standardattribute or only for DocMan? I can't seem to find any documentation about it in MSDN. We use SandCastle and SHFB